# How to fetch indirect relations through another node recursively in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have requirement where I need to traverse recursively through a graph to map out connections through an intermediate Connection node.

For example consider the Movie graph. If two people have worked on a movie, they can be considered to know each other.
With this indirect relations, I would like to map out all the connections in different tiers of a person.

```
MATCH (p1:Person {name:'Tom Hanks'})-->(m:Movie)<--(p2:Person) RETURN p1, p2, apoc.create.vRelationship(p1, 'KNOWS', {movie:m.title}, p2)
```

With this I can get the tier one connections, but I need to do this recursievely.

If the relationship 'KNOWS' was a real relations, I could run

```
MATCH (p1:Person {name:'Tom Hanks'})-[rel:KNOWS*]->(p2:Person) RETURN p1, p2, rel
```

But from what I read and tried, I cannot do this for virtual relationships.
Is there something I can do to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

just a note 'virtual' relationships are not involved in this as far as I can tell, I think you mean to say variable/unspecified relationships?

It is possible to return any length path from Tom Hanks you were on the right path, just drop the relationship type, and if you drop the <> the search is undirected paths, in any direction like this.  I don't think this is what you want, if left unbounded it would return the entire graph

```
match p=(p1:Person {name:'Tom Hanks'})-[*]-()
return p
LIMIT 10
```

Note: I added the LIMIT 10 just to be safe, it is good practice, at least until you are sure the query does what you want.

Can you give an example of a query result that you expect to see?  how far down do you want to recurse (you can specify depth e.g. *..2), and through every relationship type?

Comment: By virtual relationship I was referring to the vRelationship in apoc library. I am not able to drop the relation ship type here, As I have to do further filtering on this. I wish to create a map of people Tom Hanks knows. To see their degree of separation, and path of connection etc.
Further I would like to filter the the type of movies, maybe by genre. For example I might want to filter these connections by action movies. I would still get a map of connections of Tom Hanks, but this time, the movies through which they are connected will be action movies.